# Which are some free client side libraries that can help in development of games with HTML5 Canvas element?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, game-engine, game-physics

I am planning to develop a game with HTML5 Canvas. As handling canvas with native JavaScript is very difficult for game development, I am rather thinking to adopt any free and good client side library with good tutorial.

I have started my work with [CAAT](http://labs.hyperandroid.com/animation), but found it has lake of tutorials. I found [Cocos2d-x HTML5](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Html5), but again I faced the same issue.

Can anyone suggest me good library with good tutorial help?

P.S. :: My game contains complex physics operations, so I need to use Box2D. It will be helpful if library has integrated Box2D with it and having good tutorial of integration.

Answer (score 0):

[cgSceneGraph](http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph) can be used with Box2D. We already did it for a basket ball game.

The example page does not include yet a Box2D example, but, as I am the designer of the framework, I can help you by sending you pieces of code.

Have a look at the cgSceneGraph [examples page](http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/examples.html) (http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/examples.html).

Anyway, feel free to ask for more examples or tutorials if you need. I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate. I will definitely let you know if I'll have any questions.